# select rows as month according to timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have a table - accounts, and it has 3 columns: id , timestamp and value.
I need to create a query that returns a table which in each row it will be the month (2, 3, etc.) and the sum of the values from this month.

for example: if my table will have 3 rows from January and one row from February, the query will return a two-rows table within the first row it'll be 1 and the sum of January's values, and the second will be 2 and the sum of February's values.

I have no idea how to begin. can anyone help me?

Comment: Look into the `group by` and `sum()` Those will likely be what you want.  Also, is it MySQL or SQL Server.  They are completely different products.

Comment: Please tag properly! Now you've got 2 different answers, one for MySQL and one for MS SQL Server... Not really fair to waste people's time.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is sum the value and also use mysql's MONTH() function to pull out the month from your timestamp

```
SELECT SUM(value) as total_amount, MONTH(timestamp) as month_num
FROM table
GROUP BY month_num
```

GROUP BY is used when you have an aggregate function (in our case its SUM) to know how to group your common fields. without a group by you will have all rows summed together

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can use the DATEPART function.

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, your_date_column) AS month_
, SUM(your_value) AS value_

FROM your_table 

GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, your_date_column)
```